# how to capture sql error using vbscript

Tags: sql, vbscript, error-handling

**Updated with correct code for future use**

objRecordSet.open Sql_Statement,objconnection,1 is returning an error.

something like in sql server
Msg 50011, Level 16, State 1, Procedure xRaiseError, Line 38
Invalid Parameter Value Parameter @SerialNumber is not valid: 234f5-kjxi-vcbr

I need to capture that and store it a string. here is the function.

```
Public Function ExecuteSQLStatement_String(Sql_Statement, colname)
    On Error Resume Next 
objRecordSet.open Sql_Statement,objconnection,1
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    ExecuteSQLStatement_String = Err.description
    objRecordSet.Close
    Err.Clear
Else 
    ExecuteSQLStatement_String = objRecordSet.Fields(colname).Value
    objRecordSet.Close
End If 
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

can someone help please? Very new to vbscript. I am connecting to database and passing a sql statement. if the parameters in sql statement are correct, my function is returning the value from the recordset. But if one of the parameters are wrong, the sql statement cannot be executed. how to capture that error? Hope I am clear.
Thanks
Madhavi

Answer (score 0):

The error code and description will be in the [Err](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/sbf5ze0e(v=vs.84).aspx) object. You are already testing for the error code. To get the description use this code:

```
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    ExecuteSQLStatement_String = Err.description
    objRecordSet.Close
    Err.Clear
End If
```

Also, do not forget to turn error handling back on at the end of your function:

```
' ----turn vbscript error handler back on
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Thank you @cha. when I am debugging, as soon I hit stepover on this line
objRecordSet.open Sql_Statement,objconnection,1, 

I am getting this error:

Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.

Line (104): "objRecordSet.open Sql_Statement,objconnection,1".

Comment: Public Function ExecuteSQLStatement_String(Sql_Statement, colname)
 On Error Resume Next 
 objRecordSet.open Sql_Statement,objconnection,1,adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
 If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  ExecuteSQLStatement_String = Err.description
  objRecordSet.Close
  Err.Clear
 Else 
  objRecordSet.open Sql_Statement,objconnection,1 
  ExecuteSQLStatement_String = objRecordSet.Fields(colname).Value
  objRecordSet.Close
 End If 
 On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Now its working. Thank you @cha.